# Excel VBA Error in comparing two cells for dates

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

In my sheet columns B:C allow dates. I'm trying to create a check to see whether a date entered in C is more recent than B, if so fine, else alert the user and clear contents.
My code returns a run-time error 91 in the application.intersect line:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Dates As Range
    Set Dates = Range("C4:C12")

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Application.Intersect(Dates, Range(Target.Address)).Value > ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
    GoTo DatesMissMatch
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

DatesMissMatch:
    Target.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Value = "A2"
    MsgBox "Please re-check dates"
End Sub
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: of course, sorry... If Not Application.Intersect(Dates, Range(Target.Address)).Value > ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
    GoTo DatesMissMatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your method, but this seems to be working.

I also noticed that you were writing `A2` to `ActiveCell` instead of `Target`.  Did you want the cell in column C to update if invalid data is entered or did you intend for it to be whichever cell you move to that gets changed?

At any rate, here's a way I came up with it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then
                Exit Sub
        End If

        If Target.Column = 3 Then 'Check to see if column C was modified
                If Target.Value < Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                        Target.ClearContents
                        Target.Value = "A2"
                        MsgBox "Please re-check dates"
                End If
        End If

End Sub
```

If you want to stick with the way you are currently doing it, then I think you need to check that the Intersection is not empty as another answer concludes.

Comment: No problem, if you don't mind clicking the green checkmark to accept my answer (if this is working for you) I would appreciate it.  I like fake internet points! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop the rows and compare the dates.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = 4
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
    If ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value > ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value then
         GoTo DatesMissMatch
    End if
lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you MatthewD, on entering data in column B I get a run-time error 424 at line:  Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Made a change. You needed to add dim ws and set ws lines. so ws would be the current worksheet.

Comment: A beginner such as I am, tinkering with this code puts me in all sorts of loops but I can't get it to work :) It seems that I ought to better define the working range and when the loop stops.

Comment: You can put Target.ClearContents  Target.Value = "A2"     MsgBox "Please re-check dates"     in the loop instead of the goto.  That way you only have one loop.  When you get to a missmatch you do what you need and then move on to the next row. Or you can do an Exit Do to get out of it if you needed to.

Comment: @Cats and Dogs  There are lots of Excel VBA tutorials out there.  Most free. Like this one. It is not professionally done but covers the basics and give you good exposure to techniques. http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf

Comment: I hope to not have taken too much of your time. Thank you very much for the link as for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just have to check the intersect than do the compare.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Dates As Range
    Set Dates = Range("C4:C12")

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Dates, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value < Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
            GoTo DatesMissMatch
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

DatesMissMatch:
    Target.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Value = "A2"
    MsgBox "Please re-check dates"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this has gotten me into some loop.